# Tableau range of dates

Tags: tableau-api, business-intelligence, tableau-desktop

When updating the report every day, I need the date in the slider to always be the maximum. That is, every day there is new data, and I need the slider to move to the new date automatically.
I definitely need the slider because I need to look at data in the range.

And is it possible to set the start date of this slider (not 2016)? For example, to look from the last date of 15 days

Or maybe do you know other decisions?

Thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIJ9i.png)

I try to create parameter:

```
{FIXED: max([Order Date])}
```

but I don't know how to apply it correctly. MaybeI don't need parameter